# Timer speed automatically increase

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following code. When I click on the button picturebox move from right to left and top to bottom. When it move to the end of the panel it again start from right to left and top to bottom. Now the problem is, after first completion of picturebox from right to left timer speed gradually increase though i set it to 200 also it seems that, this line myform.counterTop = myform.counterTop + 5; the value 5 also increase gradually. After first round, it increase a little, after second it increase little more and continues like this. Please tell me why this is happening.

```
namespace Spaceship_Invaders
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private int invaderlanded = 0;
            private int invaderstopped = 0;
            private  int counterfortop = -60;
            private  int counterforleft = 415;
            private int counterTop = -60;
            private int counterLeft = 415;
            private bool pictureboxclicked = false;
            private int timerinterval = 200;

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer mytimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Image myImage = Image.FromFile("image/Untitled6.png");
            pictureBox1.Image = myImage;
            pictureBox1.Top = counterfortop;
            pictureBox1.Left = counterforleft;
        }

        public class Spaceship
        {
            Form1 myform;
            public Spaceship(Form1 form)
            {
                myform = form;
            }            


            public void mspaceship()
            {                
                    myform.mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
                    myform.mytimer.Interval = myform.timerinterval;
                    myform.mytimer.Enabled = true;
                    myform.mytimer.Start();                    

            }     


            private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
            {

                if (myform.pictureboxclicked)
                {
                    myform.mytimer.Interval = 5;
                    myform.pictureBox1.Top = myform.counterTop;
                    //myform.pictureBox1.Left = myform.counterLeft;
                    myform.counterTop = myform.counterTop - 5;

                    if (myform.counterTop <-60)
                    {
                        //myform.pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
                        //myform.pictureBox1.Hide();                       
                        myform.pictureboxclicked = false;
                        myform.mytimer.Interval = myform.timerinterval;
                        myform.counterLeft = 415;
                        myform.counterTop = -60;
                        myform.mytimer.Stop();                       


                    }
                }     else   {

                    if (myform.counterTop > 370 || myform.counterLeft < 1)
                    {
                        //myform.pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
                        //myform.pictureBox1.Hide();
                        myform.invaderlanded++;
                        myform.textBox2.Text = myform.invaderlanded.ToString();
                        myform.counterLeft = 415;
                        myform.counterTop = -60;
                        myform.pictureboxclicked = false;
                        myform.mytimer.Interval = myform.timerinterval;
                        myform.mytimer.Stop();                    
                      }   else  {
                        myform.pictureBox1.Top = myform.counterTop;
                        myform.pictureBox1.Left = myform.counterLeft;
                        myform.counterTop = myform.counterTop + 5;
                        myform.counterLeft = myform.counterLeft - 5;
                    }
                }             

            }
        }       


        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Spaceship myspaceship = new Spaceship(this);
            myspaceship.mspaceship();

          }
```

Comment: `myspaceship()` is a very poor function name.  Function names should be UpperCamelCase verbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `mspaceship()`, you add another event handler to the timer.

The second time you click it, you have *two* event handlers which each move by 5 pixels.

Instead, you should only add the handler once.